# Access $_SESSION() from apache2 to allow reverse proxy

Tags: php, apache2

I have a public php login page and a reverse proxy to a privat service set up with Apache2 (or at least that's my goal).

I want to allow access to the reverse proxy when `$_SESSION(['loggedin'])` is set to true via php.

If my example-site.conf looked somthing like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Location />
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted area"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/html/myproxyservice/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Location>

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:1234/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:1234/
</VirtualHost>
```

could I change the Auth* stuff to something that checks if `loggedin` from $_SESSION is set to true?

Comment: Apache will need to serve the PHP page in order to read the session so setting the auth at the apache level is, if not impossible, definitely very impractical. You should consider implementing the authentication and proxy code in PHP

Comment: Implementing authentication at the proxy level will not be a simple or particularly rewarding task. I would suggest changing your session backend to something that can be shared across your backend servers, like Redis or Mysql.